# zsh completion for custom script: complete options from "case" statement

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete

I have custom script that takes:

1. optional arguments in the short/long format
2. one required command line argument

the short/long command line options are for example:

```
-r, --readonly
-m, --mount
```

for the one required arguments, these are actually specified in the script as case statements, ie `foo` and `bar` in this example:

```
case $1 in
  foo )
  :
  ;;

  bar )
  :
  ;;
```

How can I create `zsh completion` for my script, so that optional arguments are completed when argument starts with `-`, and required arguments are completed taken from my script case statement?

## UPDATE:

this is what I have so far, inspired by the answer from `@Marlon Richert`.

Suppose my custom script is called `myscript.sh` and the completion rule I have created is in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_myscript.sh`:

```
#compdef myscript.sh

_myscript () {
  local -a args

  args+=(
    {-r,--readonly}'[description for "readonly"]' 
    {-m,--mount}'[description for "mount"]' 
  )

  _arguments $args && return
}

_myscript "$@"
```

My script `myscript.sh` itself is located in `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`.

So now when i have the optional arguments `-r` and `-m` taken care of, I need to modify my completion rules, so that for the required command line argument of my script, the items from the case statement from `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh` are offered as completions.

Also, I am not sure if the syntax of the block starting on line 6 with `args+=(` in my completion script is correct. Where do I have to put the single quotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's suppose the function for which you want to define completions is called `myfunc`.

First, let's set up the actual function:

1. Put your function in a file called `myfunc`. Note:

   - This does not end in `.zsh` or `.sh`.
   - When you put a function in its own file, you do not need to add `funcname() {…}` boilerplate.
2. Make sure that the dir containing the file `myfunc` is in your `$fpath`. For example, if the file `myfunc` is located in `~/Functions`, add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

   ```bash
   fpath+=( ~/Functions )
   ```
3. Finally, autoload `myfunc` in your `~/.zshrc` file:

   ```bash
   # We pass a couple of options that make the code 
   # less likely to break:
   # -U suppresses alias expansion
   # -z marks the function for zsh-style autoloading == 
   #    `unsetopt KSH_AUTOLOAD`
   autoload -Uz myfunc
   ```

You should now be able to use `myfunc` on the command line (but without any completions yet).

Next, let's create the completion function:

1. Create a file called `_myfunc`.
2. Put into this file:

   ```bash
   #compdef myfunc

   # The line above means "This function generates 
   # completions for myfunc."
   # The combination of that line, plus the file name
   # starting with an `_`, plus having this file's 
   # parent dir in your `$fpath`, ensures this file 
   # will be autoloaded when you call `compinit`.

   # `+X` makes sure `myfunc`'s definition will get 
   # loaded immediately, even if you have not called 
   # this function yet.
   autoload +X -Uz myfunc

   # Get the definition of `myfunc` in string form.
   local funcdef="$( type -f myfunc )"

   # Get the part that matches `case*esac`, then split
   # it on whitespace and put the resulting words in an 
   # array.
   local -a words=( ${=funcdef[(r)case,(r)esac]} )

   # Keep only the words that start with `(` and end 
   # with `)`.
   # Even if you used the `case` syntax with only the 
   # closing `)`s, `type -f` will show your cases with
   # both `(` and `)`.
   local -a required=( ${(M)words:#'('*')'} )

   # `-s`: Allow options to `myfunc ` to be stacked, 
   # that is, you are allowed to specify `myfunc -rm`.
   # If not, remove the `-s` option.
   # `*:`: Let this argument be completed in any 
   # position.
   _arguments -s \
       {-r,--readonly}'[description for "readonly"]' \
       {-m,--mount}'[description for "mount"]' \
       "*:required argument:( ${required//[()]/}  )"
   ```

   - Replace `required argument` with whatever you want to call your argument.
   - Fill out descriptions for the options.
3. Again, make sure the directory in which this file is located is in your `$fpath`.
4. Make sure you do `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` in your `.zshrc` file and make sure it runs *after* the dir above has been added to your `$fpath`.
5. Restart your shell with `exec zsh` or close your terminal window and open a new one.

You now should be able to get completion for `myfunc`.

---

If `readonly` and `mount` are mutually exclusive, you'll need to rewrite the last line of the completion function as follows:

```bash
_arguments \
    (-m --mount){-r,--readonly}'[description for "readonly"]' \
    (-r --readonly){-m,--mount}'[description for "mount"]' \
    "*:required argument:( ${required//[()]/}  )"
```

Comment: the `foo` and `bar` were used as examples. These should not be hardcoded in the completion script. These should be extracted from the script that we are creating completion rules for. The script has `case` statements, and valid arguments are those case items.

Comment: @400theCat I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for you effort, but it does not work. Could you please paste the full completion file, instead of just snippets ?

Comment: also, if that is not too much to ask: if you could take my template above (in the update) a starting point, that would be fantastic. I am having difficulties to orient myself in your code.

Comment: Ah, it seems I forgot to add `autoload +X -Uz myfunc`. I also added more comments. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I have copy pasted everything, but it still does not work. Did you test it on your side ?

Comment: and for testing purposes, I have renamed my script to `myfunc`. When I do `myfunc <TAB>` it just completes files in current directory.

Comment: @400theCat Whoops, I had a typo in the completion code!  The first line should say `#compdef myfunc` without any underscore. I corrected it and now it should work. Please try again.

Comment: I get this error: `_myfunc:8: myfunc: function definition file not found`

Comment: As per step of defining the actual function (not the completion function): Make sure that the dir containing the file `myfunc` is in your `$fpath`.

Comment: did you test the code that you posted? Does it work on your side ?

Comment: Yes, I did test it & it worked. I now tested it again & it again works. I did notice one thing that can go wrong, tho: You have to run `compinit` _after_ adding the dirs containing the functions to your `$fpath`. I updated my answer with it.